# Cart Throb Permissions

Tags: cartthrob

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I am using CT permissions and the problem I am having is as long as you have permission to one item you can access all items.

I am selling access to online courses.  The permission id is the same as the category id.
So a course is on http://domain.com/courses/test/50/
and my permission is:

```
{exp:cartthrob:has_permission permissions="{segment_3}" member_id="{member_id}"}
course posting here
{/exp:cartthrob:has_permission}
```

A user will have permission for category 51 but they can also access any other category ie: 50.

Even if I hard code in the permission `permissions="50"` a customer with permission to 51 can access 50.

If a user does not have ANY permissions they cannot access anything.  But if they have permission to one they can access anything they want.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Have you contacted CartThrob developers?

Comment: yes, but their support has been lacking over the past 2-3 months

Comment: As far as I can see you are implementing the code correctly so it's hard to help unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the member ID? perhaps it's not parsing... also triple check the permissions.

Comment: hardcoding the member id does not matter either.  It doesn't matter what I use for a permission, as long as you have permission for one product you have permissions for ALL products.  Even if I use: permissions="TEST" (where TEST does not even exist) it still works.

I double checked my permission in phpmyadmin and the users only have one permission, but can access content they do not have permission to access

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me unfortunately.